# Shell Script Loop over files to exit when SQL query fails

Tags: perl, shell, exit

We have a shell script that runs to stop if one of any .pl files fails.  We want to do the same with the SQL files if they exist.  The difference is we don't always have an SQL file at that point in the loop.  So we do not always have a file_num.sql.  What we want to do is if it exist and fails, then exit the script below.  The way we have this structured is running this out of the do_updates files as such:

```
my $sqlFile = $updatesdir.'/releaseupdates_02.sql';
system("$drushcmd -r $drupalroot -u site.test.admin sql-query --file=$sqlFile") == 0 or die "$drushcmd failed: $?";
```

So below in our master loop, we want to exit the loop if a perl script containing an SQL command fails.  So let's say there is a perl script that calls a php file for 3 and 4 and if that errors out, this works, however, if an SQL file exists for 02 instead of a php file, this does not work.

```
# Declare a list of update script file numbers
FILE_NUMS="
  01
  02
  03
  04
"
# Run each update script
for file_num in $FILE_NUMS; do
  ${RELEASEDIR}/do_updates_$file_num.pl
  # Exit if an update script returns and exit status of anything other than zero
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    exit $?
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `exit $?` doesn't get the same exit code as the previous line. You can simplify this as follows:

```
${RELEASEDIR}/do_updates_$file_num.pl || exit $?
```

Even better, write robust shell scripts by adding `set -o errexit` to exit the script at the first error (but beware [caveats](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)).